# Deleted all users on mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I accidentally all my user accesses to phpMyAdmin and I have no clue how to re institute a user so I can access mysql again.

Right now I have no access to even sign in MySQL when using the commandline and phpMyAdmin just displays an error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you managed to delete the root user, I assume you have the ability to restart the mysql daemon. Try killing mysql, and restarting it:

```
mysqld –skip-grant-tables
```

then

```
mysql
```

Which should give you unfettered access to your user table.

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting the Root Password**

Connect to the mysqld server with this command:

```
shell> mysql
```

Issue the following statements in the mysql client. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
    ->                   WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The `FLUSH` statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've not just delete the table, but also the entire mysql permission database. You need now to find the script 'mysql_install_db'. Once you run it, you will recreate the mysql permissions database. Now you need recreate users for any application you've set up previously.